# Regular delegate and ProxyDelegate RxSwift

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I'm new to RxSwift and trying to implement this framework https://github.com/rubygarage/collection-view-layouts into my project.

So far I've got this:

```
extension BaseLayout: HasDelegate {
    public typealias Delegate = LayoutDelegate
}

class RxLayoutDelegateDelegateProxy: DelegateProxy<BaseLayout, LayoutDelegate>, DelegateProxyType, LayoutDelegate {
    public weak private(set) var baseLayout: BaseLayout?

    public init(baseLayout: ParentObject) {
        self.baseLayout = baseLayout
        super.init(parentObject: baseLayout,
                   delegateProxy: RxLayoutDelegateDelegateProxy.self)
    }

    static func registerKnownImplementations() {
        self.register { RxLayoutDelegateDelegateProxy(baseLayout: $0) }
    }
}

extension Reactive where Base: BaseLayout {

    public var delegate: DelegateProxy<BaseLayout, LayoutDelegate> {
        return RxLayoutDelegateDelegateProxy.proxy(for: base)
    }

    var cellSize: ControlEvent<CGSize> {

    }
}
```

But still can't figure out how I can pass image size once I've got pics. Can anyone help, please?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close. Because the delegate method returns a value, you have to implement it more like the `items` function in the UITableView reactive extension. Something like this:

```
extension BaseLayout: HasDelegate {
    public typealias Delegate = LayoutDelegate
}

class LayoutDelegateProxy
    : DelegateProxy<BaseLayout, LayoutDelegate>
    , DelegateProxyType
    , LayoutDelegate {

    init(parentObject: BaseLayout) {
        super.init(parentObject: parentObject, delegateProxy: LayoutDelegateProxy.self)
    }

    deinit {
        _cellSize.onCompleted()
    }

    public static func registerKnownImplementations() {
        self.register { LayoutDelegateProxy(parentObject: $0) }
    }

    func cellSize(indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return (try? _cellSize.value())?[indexPath] ?? CGSize.zero
    }

    fileprivate let _cellSize = BehaviorSubject<[IndexPath: CGSize]>(value: [:])
}

extension Reactive where Base: BaseLayout {
    var delegate: LayoutDelegateProxy {
        return LayoutDelegateProxy.proxy(for: base)
    }

    func items<Source: ObservableType>(_ source: Source) -> Disposable where Source.Element == [IndexPath: CGSize] {
        return source
            .bind(to: delegate._cellSize)
    }
}
```

An example of use:

```
let sizes = Observable<[IndexPath: CGSize]>.just([
    IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0): CGSize(width:  50, height:  50),
    IndexPath(item: 1, section: 0): CGSize(width: 100, height:  50),
    IndexPath(item: 2, section: 0): CGSize(width:  50, height: 100)
])

sizes
    .bind(to: baseLayout.rx.items)
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you for the answer!!
Do you know if it is possible to upgrade it in the way I don't need to path indexPath but set value based on indexPath. I mean something similar to how we use tableView / collectionView rowAtIndexPath?

Comment: Sure, just make `_cellSize` a `BehaviorSubject<[CGSize]>` and adjust accordingly. In the `cellSize(indexPath:)` method, use indexPath.row to pull the value out of the dictionary.